# Is there a need to upgrade to 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, upgrade

I have  32 bit windows7 installed on my computer with 4 GB ram, an i5 processor and I use designing software like AUTOCAD and SOLID WORKS on it, but they dont work as fast as they should. Should I upgrade to 64 bit? My computer is 64 bit enabled.

Answer (score 2):

All-in-all it's a good idea just be aware of some issues with programs not fully integrating with 64-bit, specifically, MS Outlook. Win7 64-bit with Outlook 64-bit has issues, but Win7 x64 is stable with Outlook x86 (32-bit).

I reference [this](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/461) and [this](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/473) for more information on what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! 64-bit allows for a couple really nice feature such as the ability to use pretty much all applications on the market. Also with 64-bit you can get better versions of certain products. It's hard to explain but I'll give you an example. I used to play a game called battle pirates on facebook. Now this game required 64 bit java. While I have a 64-bit system I couldn't play it because Chrome doesn't support 64-bit. Also there are certain advantages when it comes to speed and such. Plus if you have it what's the point of not using it?

Comment: On the other hand you can't run 16bit Applications with W7/64bit anymore. Don't boo `;)` -- I indeed need a couple of programms which don't have a 32bit counterpart. My favorite example: Word 97 (ok, also pretty old, but also pretty good compared to the new versions. And no, I don't like those ribbons.) is in principle 32bit, but the installer is not -- bang, no (easy) chance to get this working.